# Window Height 100% in mobile chrome

Tags: html, ios, css, google-chrome, mobile

I have a responsive website where the first div on the site fills up the entire height of the browser using `height: 100%`. Mobile Chrome Browser unfortunately hides the address bar on some devices including iPhone, iPad and many Android devices. This leads to a page jump because right after scrolling the height of the window grows plus the height of the address bar.

How do I prevent this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write some JS to determine the window size and set the height to that pixel value instead of a  percentage.  Make sure to handle orientation change events to account for that scenario as well.

Comment: Ok, this would have been my solution too. Hoped for something better though :) Thank you!

Comment: Didn't realize this question was asked until I already asked and answered somewhere else. Anyway, [here was my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40156488/172852) using JS.