# Calculating Viewport Height on Chrome Android with CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, background-image, viewport

So I noticed that mobile Chrome calculates the address bar into the viewport height. Because of this using `height: 100vh` on an element doesn't work because when the address bar scrolls the viewport height changes.

I was actually able to [find a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280077/content-jumps-vertically-on-chrome-ios-with-viewport-sizing-when-address-bar-i) that had the same issue here on ios, but after investigating further I realized that this happens on all mobile Chrome browsers. When the address bar scrolls out of the viewport and then again when scrolls into the viewport, the viewport height changes.

This causes any element using `vh` to recalculate which makes the page jump. It's extremely annoying when using a background image because it causes the image to resize on scrolling.

Here's the code and [an example](http://s.codepen.io/bootstrapped/debug/qadPkz)

```
   .jumbotron {
        background-image: url(http://example.com/image.png);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

You'll only be able to see the issue when scrolling up and down using mobile chrome.

**My question is**, I would like to know is there any way around this or if not how to calculate full height on mobile chrome without causing the page to jump (css or js).

http://s.codepen.io/bootstrapped/debug/qadPkz

---

**Update:** So as far as using jquery here's what I came up with which seems to work pretty well:

```
function calcVH() {
    $('.jumbotron').innerHeight( $(this).innerHeight() );
}
$(window).on('load resize orientationchange', function() {
  calcVH();
});
```

[Demo of working example above](http://s.codepen.io/bootstrapped/debug/pEJaBq)

I'd love to be able to do this without javascript though if someone has a CSS alternative that they know works.

Comment: I have the same problem sometimes with mobile menus on safari in iOs

Comment: Derk if you have an iOS device can you [test this out](http://s.codepen.io/bootstrapped/debug/pEJaBq)? It's the javascript solution I posted above. If it works I guess it's better than nothing... Also, when you say mobile menus, what are you referring to exactly? Thanks!

Comment: I mean a menu that drops down that is full screen when you click the hamburger icon on mobile screens. I will test it now... Here is your page on iOs: [image](http://res.cloudinary.com/derkjanspeelman/image/upload/v1473321167/image1_lfm2iu.png), and when I scroll up or down, the background image will not resize or anything. So I think this is a mobile chrome bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Here's what I went with:

**HTML**

```
<div id="selector"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#selector {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
function calcVH() {
    $('#selector').innerHeight( $(this).innerHeight() );
}
(function($) { 
  calcVH();
  $(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
    calcVH();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**PURE JS (NO JQUERY)**

```
function calcVH() {
  var vH = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
  document.getElementById("selector").setAttribute("style", "height:" + vH + "px;");
}
calcVH();
window.addEventListener('onorientationchange', calcVH, true);
```

Simply change `#selector` to whatever your css selector is. If you use the pure js version you need to use an ID unless you change `.getElementByID` to [`.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

I'm only aware of this being a problem in Mobile Chrome Android, but I'm guessing it's the same for Chrome iOS as well. You could easily add a [mobile detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser) option if you wanted so this only runs when you need it to. Personally I use [Detectizr](https://github.com/barisaydinoglu/Detectizr) which works well, but to be honest, since it's pretty lightweight as it is, adding something like this is probably not worth it unless you're already using it.

Hopefully this gets fixed soon so a javascript solution isn't necessary. Also, I tried adding the resize event in case the browser width resizes, but after seeing this question I removed it from my answer. If you want to try using those just change the above to:

**JQUERY**

```
function calcVH() {
    $('#selector').innerHeight( $(this).innerHeight() );
}
(function($) { 
  calcVH();
  $(window).on('orientationchange resize', function() {
    calcVH();
  });
})(jQuery);

$(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
```

**PURE JS (NO JQUERY)**

```
function calcVH() {
  var vH = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
  document.getElementById("selector").setAttribute("style", "height:" + vH + "px;");
}
calcVH();
window.addEventListener('onorientationchange', calcVH, true);
window.addEventListener('resize', calcVH, true);
```

Comment: That wont work? 100vh is equal to the height without the bar, but doesnt update if the bar is present/abscent

Answer (score 4):

I tried every suggestion ... but nothing works for me. Either with Chrome or IOS.

But then...I had an Idea!

**1.** You can leave the standard entry in the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

**2.** Write an JS in the Foot(be sure jQuery knows about your elements) of the site e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  (function() {
    function size() {
      // you can change here what you prefer
      if (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|nokia|opera mini|opera mobi|skyfire|maemo|windows phone|palm|iemobile|symbian|symbianos|fennec/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        var theminheight = Math.min(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.screen.height, window.innerHeight);
        //now apply height ... if needed...add html & body ... i need and i use it
        $('html body #yourelementofchoise').css('height', theminheight);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize orientationchange', function() {
      size();
    }, false);
    size();
  }());
</script>
```

**3.** No more Navigationbar of chrome or whatever will disturb your output or what you want to see

**I really hope this will help somebody !**

*Maybe this is only a template of doing it muchmuchmuch greater.*

Comment: For the lazy, the "true" viewport height can be found by "Math.min(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.screen.height, window.innerHeight);". Everything else is up to the implementer.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2023 `dvh` units are available:

```
#selector {
   height: 100dvh;
}
```